# Error in ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within = within, : One or more cells returned NA when aggregated to a mean. Check your data

Tags: r, dataframe, anova

I have data frames for every variable, the variable here being the trait "sad". But when running the code, which worked for all the other variables, it did not work for this variable. I have no clue as to how to fix this problem. Here is an image of the code and the error that went along with it:

```
sad_ANOVA <- ezANOVA(data= df_test, 
                     wid = ResponseId, 
                     dv = .(sad), 
                     within = .(Racism, PerceiverRace), 
                     type = 2)

print(sad_ANOVA)

sad_desc <- ezStats(df_test, 
                    dv = .(sad), 
                    wid = ResponseId, 
                    within = .(Racism, PerceiverRace))
```

> Error in ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within = within, : One or more cells returned NA when aggregated to a mean. Check your data.

I tried some omitting of the missing data point in the data frame, but each time I attempt to get rid of the missing data point, a new error is shown. Basically, I just need to void the fact that one data point is missing, but everything I've looked up so far hasn't worked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's easier to help if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(df_test)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: Also, please share the code you try omitting NAs with. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.